# How can i get a value with span tag in vba web scraping?

Tags: html, vba, web, web-scraping, screen-scraping

Im a begginer in web scraping, and this is my first project. Im trying to catch the value in the ADVFN website and pass it on to my sheet.

This is the link: https://br.advfn.com/bolsa-de-valores/bmf/DI1F22/cotacao

The value that i want to copy is in 3,03

Im not really sure why this isnt working:

```
Sub web_scraping_teste()

    Dim ieObj As InternetExplorer
    Dim teste As Object

    Set ieObj = New InternetExplorer
    
    ieObj.Visible = False
    
    ieObj.navigate ("https://br.advfn.com/bolsa-de-valores/bmf/DI1F22/cotacao")
    
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
    
    Set teste = ieObj.document.getElementById("quoteElementPiece1").getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText
    
    Range("A1").Value = teste
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work since the value you want is directly contained in the element with the provided id:

```
Set teste = ieObj.document.getElementById("quoteElementPiece1")

Range("A1").Value = teste.innerText
```

Note `.innerText` doesn't return an object, so you can't use Set to assign it to an object-type variable like `teste`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any browser simulator to fetch your aforementioned value from that site. You can opt for xhr like the following:

```
Sub GetValue()
    Dim S$, oVal As Object

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://br.advfn.com/bolsa-de-valores/bmf/DI1F22/cotacao", True
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        While .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        S = .responseText
    End With
    
    With CreateObject("htmlfile")
        .body.innerHTML = S
        Set oVal = .getElementById("quoteElementPiece1")
        
        If Not oVal Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox oVal.innerText
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

To execute the above script, it is not necessary to add any reference to the library.